# capture tooltip of a button using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

Am a Selenium beginner. have no idea as how to capture tooltip from the following html code.
    this is the structure of the html:

```
<a id="aui_3_4_0_1_2236" title="Graceful shut down of the platform and power-off the hardware.">
    <span id="aui_3_4_0_1_2235" class="aui-button">
        <span id="aui_3_4_0_1_2234" class="aui-button-`enter code here`content">
            <input id="_PlatformSummaryPortlet_WAR_CPFSPGPortlet10SNAPSHOT_INSTANCE_AEDwGJz6R6iD_soft" class="aui-button-input" type="button" value="Soft Shutdown" onclick="javascript:soft()" style="display: inline;"/>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

and the title have the tooltip value.
I tried the following to get the tooltip:

```
WebElement Softshtdwn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Object.SoftShutdownButton)); 
String tooltip = Softshtdwn.getAttribute("title");
String tooltip1 = Softshtdwn.getText(); 
String tooltip2 = Softshtdwn.getCssValue("title");
```

but for some reason, i get the null value in return.
Any help is appreciated.
note: cannot use by.ID as ID is dynamic.

Comment: What does the HTML around the tooltip look like?

Comment: I wish i can add a screenshot. :). here is the HTML <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a title="Power-on of the platform ">
<a title="Add a new platform to the system">
<a title="Graceful shut down of the platform and power-off the hardware.">
<span class="aui-button">
<span class="aui-button-content">
<input id="_PlatformSummaryPortlet_WAR_CPFSPGPortlet10SNAPSHOT_INSTANCE_AEDwGJz6R6iD_soft" class="aui-button-input" type="button" value="Soft Shutdown" onclick="javascript:soft()" style="display: inline;"/>
</span>
</span>
</a>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>, am looking for graceful shutdown. thanks

Comment: Have amended your post, you did include your original HTML already but it was hidden because you didn't format it correctly.

Comment: can you confirm what exact tooltip you are looking for? Your code seems to look for the 'Soft Shutdown' button (`(By.xpath(Object.SoftShutdownButton)`), is that correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely, i have given xpath for value softshutdown. but am looking for tooltip of that button which is, title="Graceful shut down of the platform and power-off the hardware."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below logic you can get tooltip

But, make sure that you are using proper and unique locator to get exactly required value.

```
String toolTip=driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getAttribute("title");
```

If you are not able to construct proper xpath then post your html code here. I would help you.

Comment: I have done the similar step. but its returning null value for me. I have added the exact HTML code in my question block. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with this locator:  By.id("aui_3_4_0_1_2236")

Comment: sorry, an error in the previous code which i pasted in my question. please find the exact code:<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a title="Power-on of the platform ">
<a title="Add a new platform to the system">
<a title="Graceful shut down of the platform and power-off the hardware.">
<span class="aui-button">
<span class="aui-button-content">
<input id="_PlatformSummaryPortlet_WAR_CPFSPGPortlet10SNAPSHOT_INSTANCE_AEDwGJz6R6iD_soft" class="aui-button-input" type="button" value="Soft Shutdown" onclick="javascript:soft()" style="display: inline;"/>
</span>
</span>
</a>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody> dont have ID

Comment: try with this locator : By.xpath("//table//td/a[3]")